# Growing infinite circles with JS and Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, recursion, closures

I want to make a simple page that grows circles from its center *ad infinitum*. I'm almost there, but I can't figure out how to repeatedly grow them (resetting the radius `i` to 0 at a certain interval and calling the function again). I assume it will require a closure and some recursion, but I can't figure it out.

```js
// Initialize canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);

// Grow a circle
var i = 0;
var draw = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  i += 4;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I'd do...

First, modify your draw function so that if the circle gets to a certain size, the i variable is reset back to zero. That starts the circle over again.

Second, add a setInterval timer to call your draw function at some time interval. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp for details.

This setup will cause draw() to be called regularly, and the reset of i to zero makes it repeat.

Comment: thanks for the response. the thing is: if circle 1 starts growing, then after i > x, i start growing circle 2 and reset i to 0, then circle 1 stops growing where i = x. i would like to have each circle grow indefinitely, where the image rendered looks like an expanding bullseye.

Comment: When the circle grows to the point of being completely off the screen, you won't need to draw it anymore as it no longer will be visible.  I see you are filling the circles with a solid color, so once the circle is full size, you can just set the background color of the window to the circle color.

Answer (score 0):

So this did indeed require a closure. We wrap the initial function in a closure, and call it's wrapper function, which reinitializes I every time when called. `draw()` grows a single circle, and `drawIt()()` starts  a new circle.

```js
var drawIt = function(color) {
    var i = 0;
    return function draw() {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      i+=1*growthFactor;
      // Growing circles until they are huge
      if (i < canvas.width) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        if (i === spacing) {
          circles++
          drawIt(nextColor())();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  drawIt(nextColor())();
})();
```